Writing POST parameters in POST requests with eventData
I'm trying to scrape a website using requests and a recaptcha decoding service. The decoding service is working perfectly. However, I'm not sure how to pass the following parameters :
'{"eventData":
   {"No":"",
    "Municipality":"",
    "ZipCode":"",
    "Category":"",
    "Region":"",
    "PageSize":"10",
    "Token": "solved_captcha",
    "PageNumber":"1"}
}'


As of now, my script looks like this :
def solve_captcha():
   username = 'username'
   password = 'password'
   authtoken = ''

   captcha_dict = {
       'googlekey': '6LcPhWMqAAAAAJoAwdqRpnMSCiCARBbwGKtDt3r7',
       'pageurl': 'url',
       'action': "examples/v3scores",
       'min_score': 0.3
   }

   # Create a json string
   json_captcha = json.dumps(captcha_dict)

   client = deathbycaptcha.SocketClient(username, password, authtoken)
   captcha = client.decode(type=5, token_params=json_captcha)
   return captcha['text']

data = '{"eventData":{"No":"","Municipality":"","ZipCode":"","Category":"","Region":"","PageSize":"10","Token":"' + solve_captcha() + '","PageNumber":"1"}}'

r = requests.post(
   'url',
   cookies=cookies,
   headers=headers,
   data=data,
)

However, I keep getting an error 500 message.
Maybe it's something else, but I was wondering if the error was related to the data package ?

did you print(data) at any point to see what that value string looks like?
